# "No space left on device" error in OpenWRT when there really is space

Tags: disk-space, openwrt

I ran into a problem with my application running on OpenWRT, where I write files to /tmp which is in RAM.  Even though `df` reports that about 0% is used:

```
root@OpenWrt:/tmp# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     576       212       364  37% /
/dev/root                 2560      2560         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    14680        48     14632   0% /tmp
tmpfs                      512         0       512   0% /dev
/dev/mtdblock3             576       212       364  37% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay         576       212       364  37% /
```

after I have written 3,640 0-byte files, I get the error "No space left on device".

Can anyone explain why this is happening?  In the real world case, I wouldn't *normally* have a condition like this, as I would be deleting these files, but I need to take care of this condition anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0-byte files still use space; each file uses at least one inode.  From the tmpfs documentation, the default number of inodes for tmpfs (nr_inodes) is half the number of physical RAM pages (which are typically 4K).  I suspect you have around 8MB of memory on your device?

It might be possible to increase the number of available inodes if that's what you want by issuing as root:

```
mount -o remount -o nr_inodes=7200 /tmp
```

Typically the number of used inodes in a filesystem is insignificant enough that it's not accounted by “df”.

Comment: My device has 32MB of RAM.  I'll give your suggestion a try!  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll read up on this more, but it's definitely tied to the number of available inodes.  I bumped up the value and was able to write more files.  I guess the key is to ensure that I implement a ring buffer of sorts, and make sure that I just clear out those files as often as I can!